Python Threads do not utilize CPU cores fully
I am writing a script for an assignment, and due to the nature of the computation, it is quite slow on my Laptop. So i tried to split the main for loop into as many parts as I have CPU Cores, but when running, every single core is only used 25%. Essentially my question is this: how can i make python utilize the full CPU?
The code looks like this:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os
import threading as thr
plt.close('all')

os.system("sudo renice -n -19 -p " + str(os.getpid()))

sinogram = np.random.rand((120, 240)) # for illustration purposes

N = np.shape(sinogram)[1] # width
M = np.shape(sinogram)[0]

threads = []
nthreads = 8
results = [None] * nthreads

for i in range(nthreads):
    srange = range(int((i)*M/nthreads), int((i+1)*M/nthreads))
    t = thr.Thread(target=backproject_threaded, args=(sinogram,srange,results,i))
    print("started thread " + str(i) + " with srange " + str(srange))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

backarray = np.zeros([N,N])
for i in range(nthreads):
    threads[i].join()
    backarray += results[i]
        
plt.imshow((backarray), cmap='gray')

with backproject_threaded being:
def backproject_threaded(sinogram, srange, results, index): 
    N = np.shape(sinogram)[1] # width
    M = np.shape(sinogram)[0] # height (number of projections)
    backarray = np.zeros([N,N])

    for s in srange:
        angle = np.pi*s/M # angle of axis
        for y in range(N):
            for x in range(N):
                # project coordinate onto rotating axis
                z = np.cos(angle) * (x-N/2) + np.sin(angle) * (y-N/2) # axis-coordinate
                # select the closest coordinate in sinogram(s, :)
                sn = max(0, min(int((z+N/2)), N-1))
                # add this value to backarray value
                backarray[N-y-1, x] += sinogram[s,sn]
    results[index] = backarray
    print("thread " + str(index) + " stopped")
    return backarray

The computation yields the expected result, but this is what i see in htop:
view of htop showing cores are at 20%
How can i make this go faster?
This should be a very easy thing to multithread, because the threads don't write onto the same object, and otherwise only read from sinogram.
As you can see, I tried to set the niceness, but this has no effect. Also, i tried this os.environ["OPENBLAS_MAIN_FREE"] = "1", but it doesn't help either.
My hope was that with 8 Threads (my number of cores), it would go eight times as fast, but the cores are not utilized fully.
Also, I tried to comment out all the print statements, but this did nothing either.

Scaling CPU-bound work via threads will not work in python because of GIL. You can try using alternative approaches, for example, separate processes (instead of threads)

Your code could be vectorized for a start. Vectorization doesn't mean that it runs in //. But firstly, it is a way bigger source of performance increase than your 8 threads (for some code, you can gain a x1000 with vectorization. When you don't expect more than x8 with 8 threads parallelisation). And, secondly, if it is not vectorized, there is no chance that OPENBLAS thread can help neither: as is, you are asking numpy to do operations one by one. Whereas, if you were asking it to do them by batch, it could decide to do them in parallel.

So, that is not at all an answer to "how to use threads for parallelisation in python" (the answer to that is, in short, "you don't". Either use multiprocessing, or you use thread in another langague, like using ctypes to write your multithreaded C code called from python). But since your real objective is to accelerate code, the 1st step is not to use thread. The first step is to remove those double python for loops and vectorize your code. You will gain more than the expected x8. And maybe, numpy will even use threads for you

Note that Numpy is generally much slower on scalar than Python. Numpy is really not meant to be used for that but for relatively big arrays. The overhead of a Numpy function calls is huge (e.g. 0.5~5 µs) compare to the computational time required to do the operation on small array (even expensive cos operations typically takes no more than dozens of ns per item nowadays, and significantly less in practice on recent CPUs with a good x86-64 backend math library like SVML). Because of that arrays typically need to have at least hundreds of items to use efficiently the CPU computing power.

How would i vectorize it, when i need the index information as well?

As a general rule, multithreading is not well suited to CPU intensive work. It is best for I/O bound activities. For high CPU utilisation one would typically use multiprocessing.
I've eliminated irrelevant parts of your code to demonstrate a pattern that could be used.
This takes no account of whether (or not) numpy is appropriate in this use-case:
import numpy as np
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
import os
import time


def backproject_process(sinogram: np.ndarray, srange: range) -> np.ndarray:
    M, N = np.shape(sinogram)
    backarray = np.zeros([N, N])
    for s in srange:
        angle = np.pi * s / M  # angle of axis
        for y in range(N):
            for x in range(N):
                # project coordinate onto rotating axis
                z = np.cos(angle) * (x - N / 2) + np.sin(angle) * (
                    y - N / 2
                )  # axis-coordinate
                # select the closest coordinate in sinogram(s, :)
                sn = max(0, min(int((z + N / 2)), N - 1))
                # add this value to backarray value
                backarray[N - y - 1, x] += sinogram[s, sn]
    print(f"Process {os.getpid()} completed")
    return backarray


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sinogram = np.random.rand(120, 240)  # for illustration purposes

    M, N = np.shape(sinogram)

    nprocs = 8
    start = time.time()
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as exe:
        futures = []
        for i in range(nprocs):
            srange = range(int(i * M / nprocs), int((i + 1) * M / nprocs))
            future = exe.submit(backproject_process, sinogram, srange)
            futures.append(future)
        backarray = np.zeros([N, N])
        for f in as_completed(futures):
            backarray += f.result()
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Duration = {end-start:.2f}s")

Output:
Process 5606 completed
Process 5608 completed
Process 5604 completed
Process 5609 completed
Process 5605 completed
Process 5610 completed
Process 5603 completed
Process 5607 completed
Duration = 2.42s

Platform:
macOS Sonoma 14.5
Apple Silicon M2 (effectively 8 CPUs)
Python 3.12.3


You might clarify that your general rule is specific to CPython.
